# Создание папки с помощью скрипта в Visual studio

Tags: .net

Делаю консольное приложение .net и мне нужна часть кода, которая создавала бы папку в определенном месте (с:\ допусти), пока только изучаю программирование

Answer (score 3):

Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\mouse");

Answer (score 2):

Код на C#:

```
 System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:/папка/подпапка");
```

Comment: System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(("C:\mouse")); - выдает 2 ошибки

Ошибка CS1022 Требуется определение типа или пространства имен, либо признак конца файла.

Ошибка CS1026 Требуется ")" ConsoleApp3

Comment: Просто используйте не обратный слеш

Comment: Ошибки остались и ничего не поменялось

Answer (score 1):

Вы просили часть кода. Минимальная программа, использующая этот метод выглядит так:

```
using System;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:/папка/подпапка");
    }
}
```